# Am I responsible for closing the cursor passed to a custom CursorWrapper class constructor?

Tags: android

I've created some CursorWrapper class

```
public class DogsCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
    public DogsCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Dog getDog() {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setDogId(getInt(getColumnIndex(DogTable.ID)));
        dog.setDogName(getString(getColumnIndex(DogTable.NAME)));
        dog.setDogKind(getString(getColumnIndex(DogTable.KIND)));
        return dog;
    }
}
```

Then i use queryDogs method to fill a cursor and then return an instance of wrapper class

```
private DogsCursorWrapper queryDogs() {
    Cursor simpleCursor = db.query(
            DogTable.TABLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null);
    DogsCursorWrapper dogsCursor = new DogsCursorWrapper(simpleCursor);
    // simpleCursor.close(); // this line causes an error in runtime
    return dogsCursor;
}
```

Next step i call the method above in method below:

```
private void loadDogs() {
    DogsCursorWrapper dogsCursor;
    dogs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        dogsCursor = queryDogs();
        dogsCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!dogsCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            dogs.add(dogsCursor.getDog());
            dogsCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } finally {
        dogsCursor.close();
    }
}
```

In fact i do close the `dogsCursor` in my last method and my question is: didn't i miss some cursor that i have to close? To be clear i have some doubts about `simpleCursor` in `queryDogs` method. Should i close that one?

Is it correct decision to use custom DogsCursorWrapper class in this way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that has been commented out:

```
// simpleCursor.close(); // this line causes an error in runtime
```

is unnecessary. I think you're asking: Does it make a copy of the cursor? The answer is no. The cursor wrapper uses the cursor that is passed in.

The easiest way to verify that is to do:

```
private DogsCursorWrapper queryDogs() {
    Cursor simpleCursor = db.query(
            DogTable.TABLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null);
    DogsCursorWrapper dogsCursor = new DogsCursorWrapper(simpleCursor);
    simpleCursor.close(); // this line causes an error in runtime
    if (dogsCursor.isClosed()) { // Because of this
        Log.w(TAG, "Houston we have a problem...");
    }
    return dogsCursor;
}
```

Running this code demonstrates that closing the original cursor also closes the cursor held by the CursorWrapper.